# "Please run 'make modules_prepare'" issue when installing NDISWrapper

Tags: ndiswrapper

My router went down, so I have a temporary one installed right now that has no Wifi. I decided to pick up a USB Wifi dongle, and I want to use my Ubuntu server as the bridge. I have the driver installed, and was following the guide for setting up NDISWrapper on the [Ubuntu Community manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper). When I run `ndiswrapper -l`:

```
rt2870 : driver installed
    device (0846:9012) present
```

... So I assume that it is installed. I then run `depmod -a` and get no output (assuming it works correctly), and then `modprobe ndiswrapper`... But that returns `FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.`

This error seems weird to me, but I'll bite. I google the issue further, and find some people telling me to install 1.58 from the NDISWrapper website on Sourceforge. I try to run `make` in the extracted folder, but get this error:

```
Makefile:41: *** Please run 'make modules_prepare' in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17.  Stop.
```

Still not working! But why did the previous `ndiswrapper` commands work? The output of `ndiswrapper -v` shows that it's (mostly) installed:

```
ERROR: Module ndiswrapper not found.
module version is too old!
utils version: '1.9', utils version needed by module: '0'
module details:
ERROR: Module ndiswrapper not found.

You may need to upgrade driver and/or utils to latest versions available at
http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net
```

This is getting very irritating, but I don't know where to go from here. When I run `uname -r`, I get `3.5.0-23-generic`, if that helps any (a lot of scripts are asking for it)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like ndiswrapper needs some preparation on the kernel headers to be able to use them. Execute the following in a terminal:

`cd /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17`

`sudo make modules_prepare`

After this, compile the ndiswrapper 1.58 module.

Comment: `make: *** No rule to make target 'modules_prepare'.  Stop.`

Comment: Running `make` on `ndiswrapper` now gives the same error message?

Comment: `Makefile:41: *** Please run 'make modules_prepare' in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17.  Stop.`

Comment: The strange thing is, that it's asking for the 3.5.0.17 headers, however you are running 3.5.0.23. Check where `/lib/modules/3.5.0.23-generic/build` points to.

Comment: What command do I run to find that out?

Comment: Run `ls -l /lib/modules/3.5.0-23-generic`, you will see where `build` points to, if it exists at all (it's a symlink).

Comment: `$ ls -l
4520
xrwx  1 root root      32 May 12 18:31 build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17/`

Comment: It's pointing to an older version of headers, run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic` to fix it for the current kernel.

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-3.5.0-23-gener[sudo] password for luke:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic'`

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get update` and try the previous command again?

Comment: Same message, no change

Comment: Do you have internet access? The `apt-get update` seemed OK? How did you install the actual kernel?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8773/discussion-between-grimpitch-and-luke)